# Valet not parking domains

Tags: laravel, macos, laravel-valet

I have a list of projects I want to server thru Laravel Valet:

- ~/Projects/site1.test
- ~/Projects/site2.test
- ~/Projects/site3.test

I ran `cd ~Projects/site1.test && valet park` but when I do `ping site1.test` I get `Request timeout for icmp_seq 0`.

When I do `valet open` within `~/Projects/site1.test` I am sent to `site1.test.test` which is wrong and I get a 404 error.

I still have `192.168.10.10 site1.test` in my hosts file for when I'm running Homestead and it works fine with vagrant.

What am I doing wrong with Valet?

Comment: Always hit your domain with http:// for the first time.

Comment: I think you're meant to run `valet park` at the directory which contains your sites, rather than inside one of the directories. Try `cd ~/Projects && valet park`. Additionally, your project folders shouldn't include the TLD, Valet is set to use `.test` as a TLD by default and your folder name corresponds to the host without the TLD. So you should have a folder `~/Projects/site1`, which would then respond to `site1.test`.

Comment: @Jonathon I tried changing the dir to just `site1`, used `valet park` on the Projects dir and also removed the reference in hosts file, but I still get this: `> PING site1.test (192.168.10.10): 56 data bytes > ping: sendto: Host is down`

Comment: The DNS issue was fixed by restarting DnsMasq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I suggest you do a valet forgot in the ~Projects/site1.test directory and run valet park in ~/Projects

2) Don't name your directories like dirname.test, if you just create folders inside of /Projects you will be fine.
For example: /Projects/testproject will be http://testproject.test

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet#the-park-command